# When I am trying to round a label it won't work

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to round a label. I have attached the label to my code already. I named the label: label. I try to run this:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.height / 2
```

This keeps the label a box. When I use a button with this, it round it. Why is this and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: because you probably put that line of code in a place where layout information is not present yet. Where is that code written?

Comment: I placed it in viewDidLoad. This is where I put the ones for buttons and they worked.

Comment: that is too early in the view life cycle, put it somewhere layout information is present, e.g. `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Why would buttons work in viewDidLoad and not the Label?

Comment: try setting `label.layer.masksToBounds = true` before setting the corner radius

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Adding label.layer.masksToBounds = true fixes the issue.

Thanks Bruno for the answer!

Comment: The same effect can be achieved using

labe.clipsToBounds = true